# ApplicationXtender cannot do annotation on Web Access?

Tags: web-applications

Recently My team spend more then 3 weeks to find solution how to do **Annotation** for **ApplicationXtender Web Access**. We already set the **privilege** but still the **Annotation toolbar is not display**. Anyone can help? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using IE? Is it running in thin-client mode? What version of ApplicationXtender are you running? Are all of the web client components installed?

Comment: Already Fix. The problem is AccessRight not properly set by the Administrator. Thanks